# matplotlib plot data with nans

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm surprised how few are the posts relating to this problem. Anyway...
here it is:
I have csv data files containing X values in the first column, and several Y values columns thereafter. But for a given X value not all Y series have a corresponding value. Here is an example:

```
0, 16, 96, 99
10, 88, 45, 85
20, 85, 61, 10
30, 30, --, 45
40, 82, 28, 82
50, 23, 9, 61
60, 40, 77, 0
70, 26, 21, --
80, --, 58, 99
90, 1, 14, 30
```

when this csv data is loaded with numpy.genfromtxt, the `'--'` strings are taken as nan which is good. But when plotting, the plots are interrupted with blanks where there is a nan. Is there an option when a nan appears to make `pyplot.plot()` ignoring both the nan and the corresponding X value?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if matplotlib has such functionality built in, but you could home-brew it doing the following:

```
idx = ~numpy.isnan(Y)
pyplot.plot(X[idx], Y[idx])
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data/14399830#14399830)

As proposed in my answer there, I'd recommend using `np.isfinite` instead of `np.isnan`. There might be other reasons for your plot to have discontinuities, e.f., `inf`

Comment: ok, from what I saw in the post you linked here, this one can be marked as duplicate as that one. Anyway, thanks for your solution.