# Plot missing points for complicated 3D list of points - Python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, missing-data, line-plot

Hi I have a 3D list (I realise this may not be the best representation of my data so any advice here is appreciated) as such:

```
y_data = [ 
         [[a,0],[b,1],[c,None],[d,6],[e,7]],
         [[a,5],[b,2],[c,1],[d,None],[e,1]],
         [[a,3],[b,None],[c,4],[d,9],[e,None]],
         ]
```

The y-axis data is such that each sublist is a list of values for one hour. The hours are the x-axis data. Each sublist of this has the following format:
    [label,value]

So essentially:

```
line a is [0,5,3] on the y-axis
line b is [1,2,None] on the y-axis etc.
```

My x-data is:

```
x_data = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Now when I plot this list directly i.e.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    ax.plot(x_data, [row[i][1] for row in y_data], label=y_data[0][i][0])
```

I get a line graph however where the value is None the point is not drawn and the line not connected.

What I would like to do is to have a graph which will plot my data in it's current format, but ignore missing points and draw a line between the point before the missing data and the point after (i.e. interpolating the missing point).

I tried doing it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399830/1800665 but I couldn't work out how to do this for a 3D list.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach that you linked to will work fine here ; it looks like the question you're asking is how to apply that approach to your data. I'd like to suggest that by factoring out the data you're plotting, you'll see more clearly how to do it.

```
import numpy as np

y_data = [ 
     [[a,0],[b,1],[c,None],[d,6],[e,7]],
     [[a,5],[b,2],[c,1],[d,None],[e,1]],
     [[a,3],[b,None],[c,4],[d,9],[e,None]],
     ]

x_data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(5):
    xv = []
    yv = []
    for j, v in enumerate(row[i][1] for row in y_data):
        if v is not None:
            xv.append(j)
            yv.append(v)
    ax.plot(xv, yv, label=y_data[0][i][0])
```

Here instead of using a mask like in the linked question/answer, I've explicitly built up the lists of valid data points that are to be plotted.

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense! But can you please explain why I am getting the following error: `ax.plot(x_data[valid],np.asarray(yvals)[valid],label=temp[0][i][0])...AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: Hm, not sure about that. I've updated the code to use a slightly different approach (rebuilding the list of y-values) that might work better.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, just tried it now. The problem is when I then plot these using ax.plot it doesn't connect the line between the point before the missing value and after the missing value. This is the problem I am trying to solve. I understand that here you create a new list which doesn't include the 'None' co-ordinates at all? The thing is what does the plotting do then for the hours where there is no co-ordinate to plot? Essentially it seems this just shortens my original list so that instead of containing 'None' that record in the list just doesn't exist at all.

Comment: the way I understand it the data that gets plotted is like this: `xv = [1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2] and yv = [0,5,3,1,2,1,4,6,9,7,1]`

Comment: Hm, `matplotlib` should draw a straight line between successive points in the plot. By omitting the co-ordinates with `None` values, you're telling `matplotlib` to just plot the defined points, and connect each of them with straight lines. If that's not what's happening for you, could you post an image of what it's doing incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the green line ? It stops partway through the graph because there's no non-`None` value for `x == 2` in the green data series, so there's no value on the right to use for interpolation. (What would be the correct value to plot there, anyway ?)

Comment: Sorry it does work correctly, basically I was forgetting it will obviously not complete the line at the beginning/end if the first/last value was 'None'

Comment: Now one more thing, my original plan was to give the user the ability to draw a rectangle threshold i.e y between 2 and 4, x between 0.5 and 1.5 for example in this graph (with the xticks as they are [0,0.5,1 etc]) then that would result in the blue, purple and red lines intersecting the rectangle and the code would then output the handles to these lines, see this image: http://i40.tinypic.com/25gccvb.png. The rectangle threshold is the pale green region.