# Unexpected plotting behaviour using matplotlib and time series data

Tags: python-2.7, time, matplotlib, pandas, time-series

I'd like to plot a line graph of a time series using matlplotlib, however matplotlib will not plot all of my data unless I use `.plot_date()` or use `.plot()` passing `o` as the argument for the markers.

If I use `.plot_date` or `.plot()` and using the '-' marker, my data doesn't plot correctly:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is happening and how it can be fixed? I need the data points to be connect with lines.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dateutil
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

plt.plot(sve2_all['MeHg ng/l']['1993-01-18':'1997-05-02'].index, sve2_all['MeHg ng/l']['1993-01-18':'1997-05-02'],'bo')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

My data is in a Pandas `DataFrame` and the index is `datetime64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a lot of `NaN` values in your Dataframe. Matplotlib only draws a line between consecutive (valid) data points, and leaves a gap at `NaN` values.

If that's the case, removing the `NaN`'s before plotting should do the trick. For example:

```
dftmp = sve2_all['MeHg ng/l']['1993-01-18':'1997-05-02'].dropna()
plt.plot(dftmp.index, dftmp,'b-')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem and your solution fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas's `Series` you can just `ser.dropna()` as @RutgerKassies suggested. However this will not work for `DataFrame`s. For DataFrames someone solved the issue using [masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data). 
Or you can just `df.fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
sve2_all['MeHg ng/l ffill']= sve2_all['MeHg ng/l'].fillna(method='ffill')
sve2_all['MeHg ng/2 ffill']= sve2_all['MeHg ng/2'].fillna(method='ffill')
sve2_all[['MeHg ng/l ffill','MeHg ng/2 ffill']].plot()
```

make sure forward filling is logical to your data model.