# recognizing date variable in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two time series of data what are not in sequential date. So when I plot them they look  weird. I don't know how I can fix it here is my code and figure. Thank you.

```
date=read_myfile['Date']
x=[dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in date]
y=read_myfile['Observed']
y1=read_myfile['Simulated']
plt.plot(x,y,color='blue');
plt.plot(x,y1,color='red');
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Two time series of data.

[image]

Comment: What's so weird about the traces? What do you want?

Comment: look at the image that I attached, the lines are not smooth. I mean I have one or two data per month and python just plot them right after each other  and doesn't consider the days between them which makes bad to present.

Comment: You can use numpy and masks as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data

Comment: @Afshin If I'm understanding correctly, the peaks and the troughs are the points in the chart? Why don't you use a `Scatter` plot instead? Also, you have the option of choosing a different x-axis represented by months, would you like to know how?

Comment: @ Jossie I am going to put this in my paper and I have already too many scatter plots and I wanted to somehow use another graph. My data are daily, however I think monthly  wont solve my problem because I may  not have data for some month. Then python still plot them after each other and does not consider the missing months.