# Pandas: Plot a pivot table with NaNs on the same axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, plot

I have a pivot table made from multiple pandas timeseries with the time points not properly aligned. As a result I, have a pivot table that looks like this:

```
Time   A   B   C
1      7   NaN NaN
1.1    3   NaN 8
1.3    NaN 3   NaN
1.7    NaN NaN 12
```

I want to make a line plot with `A`, `B` and `C` all on the same axes, but the command `df.plot(kind='line')` treats the `NaN`s as significant and puts gaps in the lines. **How can I get the plot to ignore the `NaN`s and plot each pandas timeseries on the same axes as a smooth line?**

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/14399830/6626530