# Dotted lines instead of a missing value in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array of some data, where some of the values are missing

```
y = np.array([np.NAN, 45, 23, np.NAN, 5, 14, 22, np.NAN, np.NAN, 18, 23])
```

When I plot it, I have these NANs missing (which is expected)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I would like to have is a dotted line connecting the missing segments. For example in case of missing datapoint for 3, there should be a dotted line which connects existing points between 2 and 4, (the same for missing datapoints 7 and 8. If the datapoint is on the edge of the interval (datapoint 0) I would like to have a horizontal line connecting them (imagine previous/next datapoint the same as the available edge).

---

The questions I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data) here ask how to remove these empty segments (not what I want). I can solve it by creating another array which will have missing values interpolated and all other values NAN, but it looks to complex to me.

Because this looks like a common case, I hope there is an easier approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say the solution from the linked question can be directly applied here, plotting a dotted line behind the straight line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([np.NAN, 45, 23, np.NAN, 5, 14, 22, np.NAN, np.NAN, 18, 23])
x = np.arange(0, len(y))
mask = np.isfinite(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x[mask],y[mask], ls="--",lw=1)
ax.plot(x,y, color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

To account for the horizontal line in case of the edge values, one may check if they are nan and replace them with the neighboring value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([np.NAN, 45, 23, np.NAN, 5, 14, 22, np.NAN, np.NAN, 18, 23,np.NAN])
x = np.arange(0, len(y))
yp = np.copy(y)
if ~np.isfinite(y[0]): yp[0] = yp[1]
if ~np.isfinite(y[-1]): yp[-1] = yp[-2]

mask = np.isfinite(yp)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x[mask],yp[mask], ls="--",lw=1)
ax.plot(x,y, color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the edge values?

Comment: Since the edge does not have any value, it's not a priori clear what to do with it, right? So you would need to know whether it caries some meaning and what value it should therefore take.

Comment: In my questions I mentioned that in case of edge values I would like to have a horizontal line. Basically if I have `nan, 43`, I would like to have a dotted line `43, 43`.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I missed that sentence. A solution may be to check the two possible cases first, before applying the mask, as in my updated answer. It's not elegant, but working. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is way better than the stuff I was going to do.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest cant find something similar but for column dataframes, tried to convert columns to np arrays but got error ,ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types any help ples thanks

Answer (score 3):

A quick easy way for the effect you're looking for is to plot the same series twice like so:

```
y = np.array([np.NAN, 45, 23, np.NAN, 5, 14, 22, np.NAN, np.NAN, 18, 23])
x = np.arange(len(y))
_y = y[~np.isnan(y)]
_x = x[~np.isnan(y)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(_x, _y, linestyle="--", lw=.5)
ax.plot(x, y, lw=1)
```

Note that the line which connects the missing values are plotted first, then the non-missing values are an overlay (you could also use the `zorder` kwarg in the call to plot to control drawing order). The above code creates this:

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the edge values?

Comment: There are many ways to deal with missing edge data, depending on what you're trying to show. Normally I would say that preceding `nan` values should just be dropped, but if you're using `nan` to indicate useful data, such as a non-detect in a chemical analysis timeseries, then I consider using a scatter plot which fills `nan` values with the analytical method detection limit. Your reason for filling in missing data may vary, but once you've chosen a method (and a reason) you can ask another question if you want help on using `matplotlib` to plot it the way you envision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with multiple NaN on the edges. To show that, i added one NaN on each side.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([np.NAN, np.NAN, 45, 23, np.NAN, 5, 14, 22, np.NAN, np.NAN, 18, 23, np.NAN])
x = np.arange(0, len(y))

mask = np.isfinite(y)

# get first value in list
for i in range(len(mask)):
    if mask[i]:
        first = i
        break

# get last vaue in list
for i in range(len(mask)-1, -1, -1):
    if mask[i]:
        last = i
        break

# fill NaN with near known value on the edges
yp = np.copy(y)
yp[:first] = yp[first]
yp[last + 1:] = yp[last]

mask = np.isfinite(yp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x[mask],yp[mask], ls="--",lw=1)
ax.plot(x,y, color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

You **could** use `numpy.where`, to have less code, but a simple python iteration is actually more efficient here. See comparison [in my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597284/invert-edge-values-in-python-boolean-list#comment90199370_51597478).

```
ind = np.where(y)[0]
first, last = ind[0], ind[-1]
```