# Replacing part of a plot with a dotted line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to replace part of my plot where the function dips down to '-1' with a dashed line carrying on from the previous point (see plots below).

Here's some code I've written, along with its output:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [5,6,8,3,5,7,3,6,-1,3,8,5]

plt.plot(np.linspace(1,12,12),y,'r-o')
plt.show()

for i in range(1,len(y)):
    if y[i]!=-1:
        plt.plot(np.linspace(i-1,i,2),y[i-1:i+1],'r-o')
    else:
        y[i]=y[i-1]
        plt.plot(np.linspace(i-1,i,2),y[i-1:i+1],'r--o')
plt.ylim(-1,9)
plt.show()
```

Here's the original plot

[image: original plot]

Modified plot:

[image: modified plot]

The code I've written works (it produces the desired output), but it's inefficient and takes a long time when I actually run it on my (much larger) dataset. Is there a smarter way to go about doing this?

Comment: So you assume that the first value is never -1?

Comment: A possible idea would be to use masked arrays, e.g. `y_masked = np.ma.masked_where(y == -1, y)`. Plotting this would miss out `-1` values, so you'd still need to do some work to show the previous value and add a dotted line (maybe plot only masked values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `numpy` functionality to cut your line into segments and then plot all solid and dashed lines separately. In the example below I added two additional `-1`s to your data to see that this works universally.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y = np.array([5,6,-1,-1, 8,3,5,7,3,6,-1,3,8,5])
X = np.arange(len(Y))

idxs =  np.where(Y==-1)[0]

sub_y = np.split(Y,idxs)
sub_x = np.split(X,idxs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

##replacing -1 values and plotting dotted lines
for i in range(1,len(sub_y)):
    val = sub_y[i-1][-1]
    sub_y[i][0] = val
    ax.plot([sub_x[i-1][-1], sub_x[i][0]], [val, val], 'r--')

##plotting rest
for x,y in zip(sub_x, sub_y):
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-o')

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Note, however, that this will fail if the first value is `-1`, as then your problem is not well defined (no previous value to copy from). Hope this helps.

Comment: I know I've already accepted the answer, but is there a way to do this without using loops? This is proving to be prohibitively expensive when I have long lists of -1s

Comment: @Lupacante I think the other answer is actually the better solution. With a little adjustment you should be able to get what you are after. Oh, and it is no problem at all if you change your mind and accept another answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something similar without the loops:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a data frame from the list
a = pd.DataFrame([5,6,-1,-1, 8,3,5,7,3,6,-1,3,8,5])

# Prepare a boolean mask
mask = a > 0

# New data frame with missing values filled with the last element of   
# the previous segment. Choose 'bfill' to use the first element of 
# the next segment.
a_masked = a[mask].fillna(method = 'ffill')

# Prepare the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(a_masked, ls = '--', lw = 1)
ax.plot(a[mask], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also highlight the negative regions by choosing a different colour for the lines:
[image]

My answer is based on a great post from July, 2017. The latter also tackles the case when the first element is NaN or in your case a negative number:
[Dotted lines instead of a missing value in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176584/dotted-lines-instead-of-a-missing-value-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get it exactly the same? I like this answer more, as it doesn't use loops. The above one is turning out to be prohibitively slow when there a long strings of -1s.

Comment: Got it - I'll post my own solution in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant, but here's something that doesn't use loops which I came up with (based on the above answers) which works. @KRKirov and @Thomas Kühn , thank you for your answers, I really appreciate them

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a data frame from the list
a = pd.DataFrame([5,6,-1,-1, 8,3,5,7,3,6,-1,3,8,5])

b=a.copy()
b[2]=b[0].shift(1,axis=0)
b[4]=(b[0]!=-1) & (b[2]==-1)
b[5]=b[4].shift(-1,axis=0)
b[0] = (b[5] | b[4])
c=b[0]
d=pd.DataFrame(c)

# Prepare a boolean mask
mask = a > 0

# New data frame with missing values filled with the last element of   
# the previous segment. Choose 'bfill' to use the first element of 
# the next segment.
a_masked = a[mask].fillna(method = 'ffill')

# Prepare the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(a_masked, 'b:o', lw = 1)
ax.plot(a[mask], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
ax.plot(a_masked[d], color=line.get_color(), lw=1.5, marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```