# matplotlib ignore missing data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, missing-data

The question has already been asked and has a [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data) using masks.

Asking again because I'd like to know if is there a way to make matplotlib handle missing data on its own, something like if any of x or y data is missing just ignore it and draw a line through it.

Here's some sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

x = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
plt.plot(x,y, "*-")

x_nan = np.arange(100)
y_nan = np.asarray([np.nan] * 100)
y_nan[::10] = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
plt.plot(x_nan,y_nan,"*-")

mask = np.isfinite(y_nan)
plt.plot(x_nan[mask],y_nan[mask],"--")

plt.show()
```

The second plot draws dots only for the non-nan points, but no line through them.

The easiest way to make it look like the first is to define a mask like in the third plot. I'd like to know if is there a way to make matplotlib behave like this automatically without the extra mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No!

Long answer: One could indeed imagine that some feature would be built into matplotlib's `plot` function that would allow to remove `nan`s from the input.

However, there is none.

But since the solution is essentially only one extra line of code, the fact that matplotlib does not provide this functionality is bearable.

Just as a fun fact: Interestingly, a `scatter` plot indeed irgnores `nan` values, e.g.

```
line, = plt.plot(x_nan,y_nan,"-")
scatter = plt.scatter(x_nan,y_nan)
print(len(line.get_xdata()))       # 100
print(len(scatter.get_offsets()))  # 10
```

while the line has still 100 points, the scatter only has 10, as all nan values are removed.