# Data not appearing on a python plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with date as index, floats as columns, filled with mostly NaN and a few floats.

I am plotting this dataframe using :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot(df2[11][2:], linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,label='xx')
ax.set(xlabel='xx', ylabel='xx', title='xx')
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

The plot window open but with no data appearing. But if I use markers instead of line, the data point will appears.

What should I correct to plot my graphs as lines?

edit  Thanks, it worked like this :

```
s1 = np.isfinite(df2[11][2:])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot(df2.index[2:][s1],df2[11][2:].values[s1], linestyle='-',linewidth=2,label='xx')
ax.set(xlabel='xx', ylabel='xx',title='xx')
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case matplotlib won't draw a line between points separated by NaNs. You can mask NaNs or get rid of them. Have a look at the link below, there are some solutions to draw lines skipping NaNs.

[matplotlib: drawing lines between points ignoring missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(df2[11][2:], linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,label='xx')
plt.set(xlabel='xx', ylabel='xx', title='xx')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```