# Is there a plotting package in python which handles missing values without omitting x-axis values/labels/scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bokeh, missing-data

I am plotting certain line plots where there might occur missing values. These plots certain values against days of a week. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to handle the missing values since, if the values are missing, the plot (eg: using matplotlib) does not show up the corresponding labels of x-axis which is very important.

I tried with matplotlib like what has been said https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614698/2602324 here. I also tried out bokeh plots, seaborn. In all these cases, the library requires that the length of values for x-axis and y-axis should be the same.

Some ways I tried out:

- matplotlib, seaborn

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a = [None, 585, None, None, None, None, None]
b = [None, None, None, 50, None, None, None]
x_ticks = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

sns.lineplot(x_ticks, b, linestyle='-', label='Current Week', marker='^')
sns.lineplot(x_ticks, a, linestyle='-', label='Previous Week', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

[image]

In this case, there were problems such as the order of x-axis label changes (I think it is sorting based on the values of y). And also, the values of x are not showing up for which the y values are missing.

- Bokeh

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("line.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
a = [nan, 585, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
b = [nan, nan, nan, 50, nan, nan, nan]
x_ticks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# add a line renderer with a NaN
nan = float('nan')

p.line(x_ticks, a, line_width=2)
p.line(x_ticks, b, line_width=2)
p.circle(x_ticks, a)
p.circle(x_ticks, b)

show(p)
```

[image]

Here, the scale of x-axis changes. Maybe I need to do something to keep the labels intact but still, I need the whole set of labels (x) to be displayed even if the values are missing. The values I have used in the above cases to plot are nothing but a worst-case scenario which is likely to occur (but not often).

---

Since this was put on hold, I think I will give more clarity on what I actually am searching for. I want a line plot with markers which handles the missing values without perturbing the values of x in any way.

[image]

This way, in the worst-case scenario, if there are many missing values (here it has only two values and the rest are missing) it shows up the points with just the markers. Otherwise, it should be like this:
[image]

Here there are 3 values available and the rest are missing. In both cases, the values and the order of x-axis are preserved.

P.S. I drew the last two plots using excel.

Comment: I have edited the above post (bottom) by giving more clarity on what I actually need.

Comment: By default, Bokeh will attempt to automatically set the data bounds of plots to fit snugly around the data. You can specify `x_range` and `y_range` to prevent this. More information/examples can be found in the docs: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#setting-ranges

Comment: Thanks @Jasper for your input. I got the solution and I have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim helps to force the limits for X axis and similarly set_ylim for y axis. This was exactly what I was searching for.