# Pandas- How to add a column with entries skipping rows?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I have three time series arrays. Two of them have values at 3-hour intervals, and one has values at 6-hour intervals. I want to add them all to the same dataframe for easy time series plotting with timestamps set as the index, but I'm not sure how to add the 6-hour interval array to skip rows so the values are placed at the correct times.

I have a working example below.

```
import pandas as pd

A = [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]
B = [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.]
C = [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.                         ]

data = { 'A_col': A,
         'B_col': B
       }
df   = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A_col','B_col'])
print(df)
```

> ```
>    A_col  B_col
> 0    1.0   11.0
> 1    2.0   12.0
> 2    3.0   13.0
> 3    4.0   14.0
> 4    5.0   15.0
> 5    6.0   16.0
> 6    7.0   17.0
> 7    8.0   18.0
> 8    9.0   19.0
> 9   10.0   20.0
> ```

Essentially I want to add C as a column and have its values occur at indices 1, 3, 5, etc to line up with A_col's values. How do I do that efficiently? Pandas tells me each column has to be the same size. (The actual time series arrays I'm working with are quite long.) I want this to generate a time series plot with all the values at the right positions along the x-axis.

Note- I'm relatively new at pandas but have greater experience with numpy.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the data to match the same length of index

Comment: Depends, how do you want to fill the missing time steps? zeros? mean?

Comment: Assuming df.plot will skip NaN's, that would be preferred. I definitely do not want them to be zeros, as that would be interpreted as actual values of 0.

Comment: Then I think you already have an answer below :)

Comment: That NaN answer replaces C's values, which I do not want to do.

Comment: Thank you for adding a df=  line, those help tremendously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along this line:

```
df['C'] = np.nan
df.iloc[1::2, -1] = C    
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A_col  B_col     C
0    1.0   11.0   NaN
1    2.0   12.0   2.0
2    3.0   13.0   NaN
3    4.0   14.0   4.0
4    5.0   15.0   NaN
5    6.0   16.0   6.0
6    7.0   17.0   NaN
7    8.0   18.0   8.0
8    9.0   19.0   NaN
9   10.0   20.0  10.0
```

Comment: By replacing C's values with NaN's, this does not preserve the values in C. I want C to retain its values but have them inserted into the dataframe at the indices I indicted.

Comment: Just pass `C` instead of `range(5)`?

Comment: Thank you, this got the dataframe to populate the way I wanted to and then I used Markus Dutschke's answer on this question to make the plot- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Truth series for odd's and group on those to set the values you need:

```
df['Truth'] = df['A_col'] % 2 == 1

   A_col  B_col  Truth
0    1.0   11.0   True
1    2.0   12.0  False
2    3.0   13.0   True
3    4.0   14.0  False
4    5.0   15.0   True
5    6.0   16.0  False
6    7.0   17.0   True
7    8.0   18.0  False
8    9.0   19.0   True
9   10.0   20.0  False
```

Here are two examples on what you can do with it, as i'm not sure what your trying to achieve, but i hope this helps you:

```
df.loc[df['Truth'] == True, 'Truth'] = df.loc[df['Truth']].groupby(df['Truth']).cumsum()
df.loc[df['Truth'] == False, 'Truth'] = df.loc[df['Truth'] == False]['A_col']

   A_col  B_col  Truth
0    1.0   11.0      1
1    2.0   12.0      2
2    3.0   13.0      2
3    4.0   14.0      4
4    5.0   15.0      3
5    6.0   16.0      6
6    7.0   17.0      4
7    8.0   18.0      8
8    9.0   19.0      5
9   10.0   20.0     10
```

does this make sense on how you can deal with value groupings you need? If you give some info on what the end result looks like, i can modify my solution to match it,

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

A = [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]
B = [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.]
C = [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.                         ]

data = { 'A_col': A,
         'B_col': B
       }
df   = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A_col','B_col','C_col'])

C_iterator=0
df_size = len(df)
for position in range(df_size):
    if position%2 !=0:
        df['C_col'].loc[position] = C[C_iterator]
        C_iterator+=1
    else:
        pass

df['C_col']=df['C_col'].astype(float)
print(df)

   A_col  B_col  C_col
0    1.0   11.0    NaN
1    2.0   12.0    2.0
2    3.0   13.0    NaN
3    4.0   14.0    4.0
4    5.0   15.0    NaN
5    6.0   16.0    6.0
6    7.0   17.0    NaN
7    8.0   18.0    8.0
8    9.0   19.0    NaN
9   10.0   20.0   10.0
```