# Why Graph Line is not Displaying in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just Started learning matplotlib in this i can see my graph but i cant see my graph line

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Language': ["Assembly", "C++", "Java", "C", "Python", "Php", "Ruby", "Java"],
        'Date': ['1-1-2008', '1-1-2009','1-1-2010', '1-1-2011', '1-1-2012', '1-1-2013', '1-1-2014','1-1-2015'],
        'Cool': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }
)

pivot = file.pivot(index='Date', columns='Language', values='Cool')
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.plot(pivot.index, pivot.Java)
```

Comment: Try printing `pivot.Java`, is it what you are expecting?

Comment: try this:`plt.plot(pivot.index, pivot.Cool)`

Comment: i want that graph to draw a line @DavidG

Comment: @r-beginners Cool not working its showing an error that Cool is not defined

Comment: This will be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14399689/8881141 And please be reminded that some columns only contain one value. These will not show up because `plot` draws lines between consecutive data points

Comment: `pivot.reset_index(inplace=True);plt.plot(pivot.columns, pivot.index)` try this

Comment: @r-beginners mate with this line of code a straight line is drawen and it replaced the dates with the language name at the bottom of the graph

Comment: @Mr.T with that code two dots are displayed but there is not line linking those dots

Comment: I added linestyle='-' and marker='o' after   pivot.index, pivot.Java @Mr.T

Comment: This is the problem statement in the question. This person had the same problem you had. That's why they asked the question. Obviously, you have to adapt one of the answers to your code.

Comment: but i didn't learned numpy yet and he is using numpy how can i use that thing that i never learned and instructor didn't used numpy as well

Comment: Pandas is built on top of numpy; matplotlib utilizes numpy. If your instructor starts from pandas without teaching first the essentials, well, what can I say. Pandas indexing is very much alike to numpy indexing which is very much alike to Python indexing. I suggest you look up [array slicing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_indexing_and_slicing.htm) and [Boolean indexing](https://www.python-course.eu/numpy_masking.php), if you want to work with matplotlib. Of course, you could always retreat to base Python lists but this is way more complicated.

Comment: @Mr.T yea madam didnt told us about numpy i think i have to learn about numpy then panda and then matplot lib i have a question for u should i learn data science theory first like regression or should i first try practicing these libraries