# Draw a line between points, ignoring missing data, with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, nan

Numerous similar questions have been asked over the years, such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399689/matplotlib-drawing-lines-between-points-ignoring-missing-data), but none of the accepted answers solve my problem.

The following code:

```
x=[0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.08, 0.11, 0.14]
y1=[31.15, None, 15.24, 11.65, 13.54, 9.55]
y2=[20.3, 14.2, 5.6, 3.10, 8.8, 10.45]
plt.plot(x, y1, linestyle='-',marker='o',color='red')
plt.plot(x, y2, linestyle='-',marker='o',color='blue')
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

However, I want to force a line to be drawn between the first and third elements of y1[], without affecting how y2[] is plotted. Is this possible? I could remove the second element of x[], but this would also prevent me from plotting x[] against y2[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple function to keep only the valid data:

```
x=[0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.08, 0.11, 0.14]
y1=[31.15, None, 15.24, 11.65, 13.54, 9.55]
y2=[20.3, 14.2, 5.6, 3.10, 8.8, 10.45]

def dropnone(X, Y):
    return zip(*((a,b) for a,b in zip(X,Y) if None not in [a,b]))

plt.plot(*dropnone(x, y1), linestyle='-',marker='o',color='red')
plt.plot(*dropnone(x, y2), linestyle='-',marker='o',color='blue')
```

output:

[image]